# how do I add new item to an array in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

I am working on an anonymous web app.

Here's my schema for the user.

```
const itemsSchema = {
  name: String
}

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
  Messages: [itemsSchema]
});

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

here's the code in my message ejs template

```
<%- include("partials/header"); -%>

<h1>Say Something</h1>


<form class="" action="/message" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" name="message" placeholder="Leave a message for <%=username%> here"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="username" value="<%=username%>">Send Message</button>
</form>

<%- include("partials/footer"); -%>
```

I have been trying to add a new message to the message array using this code

```
app.post("/message", function(req, res){

  User.updateOne({username: req.body.username}, {$push: {messages: [req.body.message]}}, function(err, result){
    if (!err){
      console.log(result);
    }
  })
```

but its not updating or adding any new item to the user array. I get this prompt in the console.

```
{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }
```

Please what am I doing wrong.

I tried using;

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({username: req.body.username}, {$addToSet: {messages: [req.body.message]}}, function(err, result){
    if (!err){
      console.log(result);
    }
  })
```

Yet, new messages are not been added to the user messages array.

Comment: what is a sample content that `req.body.message` can have. Is it an array?

Answer (score 0):

Two things here:

- In your model the field is capitalized. You must use the exact same name (case sensitive) in your $push.
- The Messages field is defined to accept an array of objects (itemsSchema), but you are trying to add an array, instead of an object ({$push: {messages: [req.body.message]}}). Changing it to {$push: {messages: req.body.message}} or {$push: {messages: {...req.body.message}}} should make it work.

Also, be sure that req.body.message is an object, containing "name" property (string), as defined in your model.

[MongoDB $push documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)